# flutter leading with tabs behind actions

Tags: android, flutter, dart

how can I make tabs behind actions in appBar ?like this ! photo
[image: tabbed leading bar]

, my code look like this and I've tried to put tabs on `leading`

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: [
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.archive)),
          ],
          leadingWidth: double.maxFinite,
          leading: TabBar(
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: "Pending"),
              Tab(text: "Delivered"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Tab(text: "Pending"),
            Tab(text: "Delivered"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here how it's the output look like  => [image: output of my code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you put the tab in title instead of leading:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: [
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.archive)),
          ],
          title: TabBar(
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: "Pending"),
              Tab(text: "Delivered"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Tab(text: "Pending"),
            Tab(text: "Delivered"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the carousel_slider dependency. To get it you can visit `pub.dev` and search for carousel_slider or here's a link  https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider. I hope this helps )

```
//example image
final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
];

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgList
    .map((item) => Container(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0.0,
                      left: 0.0,
                      right: 0.0,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                              Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                            ],
                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            end: Alignment.topCenter,
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                        // child: Text(
                        //   'No. ${imgList.indexOf(item)} image',
                        //   style: TextStyle(
                        //     color: Colors.white,
                        //     fontSize: 20.0,
                        //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        //   ),
                        // ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ))
    .toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   int _current = 0;
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: [
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.archive)),
          ],
          leadingWidth: double.maxFinite,
          leading: TabBar(
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: "Pending"),
              Tab(text: "Delivered"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body:Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
 
        CarouselSlider(
          items: imageSliders,
          carouselController: _controller,
          options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 200,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              autoPlay: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
               aspectRatio: 2.0,
              viewportFraction: 1,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  _current = index;
                });
              }),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: imgList.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => _controller.animateToPage(entry.key),
              child: Container(
                width: 12.0,
                height: 12.0,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: (Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Colors.black)
                        .withOpacity(_current == entry.key ? 0.9 : 0.4)),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ]),
          
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```